# how to do equal value type comparison with ajax returns a json empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using ajax to get a returning json. Sometimes it returns an empty string. I would like to find out how to do a '===' equal value type comparison for a json empty string. For the following example, what can I put on the right side of the '===' to get a 'true' popup window (notice: this example would return 'false')? Thanks in advance!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        $.post('somefile.php', function(data){alert([]===[]?'true':'false');}, 'json');
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning false because an array is a reference type, and not a primitive type; which means if you say:

```
var a = []; var b = [];
```

`a` and `b` store references to their values, not the values themselves. So the reference to the value of `a` and the reference to the value of `b` are not the same.

To compare arrays, as far as I know, you would have to loop through all the elements and compare them one by one.

With primitive types on the other hand, you compare their values. So maybe you could return a string and compare.

Comment: This is what I get:
[]=="" ;true
[]==="" ;false
[]===[] ;false

for [] on the left being an empty string of json

Comment: That's because you are comparing a reference type with a primitive type. With the `==` operator, the array gets converted to a string behind the scenes. That's why it returns true. Point being don't compare two reference types using comparison operators.

Comment: your answer is not possible to compare array with reference type by using ===, lesson learned, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If response `data` is an empty string just try `alert(data==='[]'?'true':'false')`
If you got an array in response just check it'seems length.

```
alert(data.length?'true':'false')
```

So, if length is 0 it is falsy value for Javascript, and you'll got 'true', if it's length is 1 or greater you'll get 'false'.

Comment: that would return false, because actual return value from somefile.php is: json_encode(array());

Comment: I've updated answer, also you can add code: console.log(data) or alert (data), before your alert(...) , just to check what exectly you have in response.

Comment: I tried: alert(data==='[]'?'true':'false') giving me false

Comment: So, try to check in browsers console, using console.log(data), or alert(data) to check response value which you get in case of empty array, and use it comparison.

Comment: the console.log(data) would give me [], which is why I used [] on my sample code. thank you for trying

Comment: In that case you should check alert(data.length ?'true':'false')